# ReactJS Img Tag Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, memory-leaks

UPDATE: The images it turns out had their dimensions set for 5k resolution hence the giant ram usage. While garbage collection is kicking in on the lower res photos the site is still to ram heavy for Android Chrome. Thanks to all tho answerers.

Folks I am having a bit of an issue with ReactJS and some img tags. I am not using JSX so my code is in javascript. My splash page takes up 120 megabytes of memory however when I click to go to a section with 6 images the memory balloons up to 900 megabytes despite the images being 900kb each. I have set shouldComponentUpdate and the images are not being updated consistently. I added a random query flag to get around caching this didn't change the memory leak.

```
var Modal_Image = React.createClass({

  showModal: function(url){
    store.dispatch({type: "SHOW_MODAL", src: url});
  },
  shouldComponentUpdate: function(next_props, _){
    console.log("modal image might update");
    if(next_props.url != this.props.url){
      return true;
    }
    if(next_props.size != this.props.size){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  componentDidUpdate:function(){
    console.log("modal image updated");
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      React.createElement("div", {className: "image-holder " + this.props.size},
        React.createElement("img", {src: this.props.url, className: "home-image c-hand", alt: "", onClick: this.showModal.bind(this, this.props.url) })
      )
    )
  }
});
```

neither the size prop or the url prop is changing and the console.logs aren't reporting back any changes yet Chrome needs 800 megabytes to store these images. Any ideas or hints on dealing with memory leak issues involving images?

Additions:
 /**
  * React v15.3.0
  */

Edit:

1. removed the componentWillUnmount method.
2. removed animated fadeIn
3. removed the cache busting query flag seems to have helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be simply the image sizes. I scaled them down and implemented thumbnails and the app's memory usage shrank dramatically and garbage was collected significantly faster. The later is also interesting because it suggests that chrome persists large (> 200 megabyte) files in memory. App's total memory usage is now less than Facebook's. So watch your image dimensions closely.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate suspect is jQuery, because it adds data to the DOM node it was applied to, and this may cause a memory leak if not cleaned by jQuery. 
In addition, react is responsible for cleaning the elements it rendered, such as the the component root (`div`), and the content (the image itself).
Remove the `componentWillUnmount` method, and jQuery as well.

btw - `React.createClass` autobinds methods to `this`, so you can just call
`this.showModal` instead of `this.showModal.bind(this, this.props.url)`, and

```
  showModal: function(){
    store.dispatch({type: "SHOW_MODAL", src: this.props.url});
  },
```

Comment: unfortunately the jQuery method was added after I discovered the memory leak in order to clean up (the empty gets rid of detached dom nodes). I just removed it and the problem remains. Thanks though for the pointers. The problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: Try the chrome dev tools [memory diagnosis](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en) methods.

Comment: Yeah I used that to identify the culprit, but I will take a look again. Right now I am building a simplified version of the site to see if I can replicate the bug elsewhere.